# toggle button to switch between two language in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to added switch toggle button to change the language of my blog using a Google translate script. I found that code and it works fine.
I found this toggle button, but I don't know how to mix them with JavaScript to get the code work fine.
I want to added switch toggle button to change the language of my blog using a Google translate script. I found that code and it works fine.
I found this toggle button, but I don't know how to mix them with JavaScript to get the code work fine.

```html
<div id='google_translate_element'> </div>
<div class='menu-traslate-header'>
 
 <ul>
 
  <li><a href='#googtrans/fr'>FR</a></li>
  <li><a href='#googtrans/ar'>Ar</a></li>
</ul> 
 
</div>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'fr', 
    includedLanguages: 'ar,fr-CN' , 
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, 
    multilanguagePage: true, 
    gaTrack: true, 
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script src='//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit' type='text/javascript'/>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.menu-traslate-header ul li a' ).click(function(event) {
      window.location = $(this).attr('href');
      location.reload();
  });
});
</script>
```

the toggle switch button

```css
@use postcss-preset-env {
  stage: 0;
}

/** BEGIN CSS NEEDED FOR SWITCH **/
.on-off-toggle {
  width: 56px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.on-off-toggle__slider {
  width: 56px;
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 34px;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  transition: background-color 0.4s;
  
  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #949494;
    bottom: 3px;
    height: 18px;
    left: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .4s;
    width: 18px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  
  &:after {
    display: block;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    content: 'fr';
    color: #484848;
    padding-left: 26px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
  }
  
}

.on-off-toggle__input {
  /*
    This way of hiding the default input is better 
    for accessibility than using display: none;
  */
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.on-off-toggle__input:checked + 
.on-off-toggle__slider {
  background-color: #000;
  
  &:before {
    transform: translateX(32px);
  }
  &:after {
    content: 'ar';
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }
}

/*** END CSS NEEDED FOR SWITCH **/



/*** DEMO STYLES ONLY ***/

* { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
  font-family: OpenSans, sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="on-off-toggle">
  <input class="on-off-toggle__input" type="checkbox" id="bopis" />
  <label for="bopis" class="on-off-toggle__slider"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `location.reload()` hard reloads the page, just like hitting the "reload" button in the browser. Also note that your paste has gone a bit wrong, what should be quote symbols have become HTML entities.

Comment: no i took the right paste and it works fine

Comment: And you should still update it to proper code, because `pageLanguage: &#39;en&#39;,` should be `pageLanguage: 'en',`, `$(this).attr(&#39;href&#39;)` should be `$(this).attr('href')`, etc. - remember that you're asking other people to read your code, so please make sure you show normal code that can be easily read.